# Neo4j-ogm X-Write header is wrong on read-only transactions' first request

Tags: java, neo4j, transactions, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm using:

- spring-data-neo4j 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
- neo4j-ogm 2.1.1
- neo4j 3.0.8

and **I'm having a problem with the X-Write HTTP header set by neo4j-ogm**.

On write transactions, it is correctly set.

But I'm having a **problem with read-only transactions**. I have multiple calls to neo4j in my read-only transactions:

- POST .../db/data/transaction {"statements":[{"statement":"request1"}...]} (X-WRITE: **true**)
- POST .../db/data/transaction/1 {"statements":[{"statement":"request2"}...]} (X-WRITE: **false**)
- POST .../db/data/transaction/1 {"statements":[{"statement":"request3"}...]} (X-WRITE: **false**)
- ...

The problem is that **the first request contains the X_WRITE header with the 'true' value**. The next requests correctly have the header with the 'false' value.

**So the first request is always sent to my master node and I'm not able to send the next requests on a slave node, because all requests inside a transaction must be sent to the same neo4j node.**

Looking at neo4j-ogm source code, it seems it could maybe be due to HttpDriver.readOnly() method that is returning false when getCurrentTransaction() is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in the OGM HTTP Driver. Please raise a bug here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues

Comment: The bug has been fixed in neo4j-ogm 2.1.2-SNAPSHOT